# Why do ros programs often have difficulty stopping cleanly

Tags: ros, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello List,

I am working with different ros versions, mostly kinetic and melodic.
But my question pertains to all versions.
Often it is difficult to stop ros programs, typing control-C often is not enough.
It has to be repeated multiple times, it also take a long time to actually react.
I usually ends with "excalating to SIGTERM" or something.
I currently see this with gazebo_ros launch files.

Why is this so, what is the technical reason that a more clean and faster stop does not seem to be possible?

Regards, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304910/why-do-ros-programs-often-have-difficulty-stopping-cleanly/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2018-10-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros nodes don't exit as requested usually when you use threads. If you have threads running with a `while` loop and you missed a condition like `ros::isShuttingDown()` (or another function monitoring the ros state) then the thread will still be running even if you exit your node (in that case i use the commands `jobs` to check the processes running and kill them with `kill %1`).

When you exit a ros node with `CTRL-C` you send a signal : `SIGINT`. This signal has a default timeout and if the node takes too much time to exit another signal is sent : `SIGTERM`.

- The `SIGINT` signal is an
  interruption of your processes and
  you are able to define functions to
  handle this interruption and do
  whatever you want (usually end your
  threads and anything that can exit
  the node).
- The `SIGTERM` signal kills all the
  processes so you just end everything
  without going in another function to
  deal with it.

With `Gazebo` it's a common issue. To run, `Gazebo` needs the process `gzserver`.

**FYI :** There is also the process `gzclient` used for the `Gazebo GUI`. You can run `Gazebo` without `gzclient`, you just won't have the `GUI` but if you check in Rviz everything will work.Instead of `gzserver` which is mandatory.

The problem here is that `gzserver` takes a lot of time to exit when you send a `SIGINT` signal (I don't know why though). The default timeout is `15.0 seconds` so after that time you have the `SIGTERM` signal sent to exit `gzserver`. I use a workaround thanks to [#q11353](https://answers.ros.org/question/11353/how-to-delay-escalation-to-sig-term-after-sending-sig-int-to-roslaunch/) to change the default timeout of the signals. In the file :

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py
```

You can modify this line to the value you want (not too low to allow other nodes to exit cleanly)

```
_TIMEOUT_SIGINT = 15.0 #seconds
```

You can also try to increase this value to see how much time it takes to actually exit cleanly if you want.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-10-05**:
Thanks for the  thorough answer!
In launch files and using separate processes it is difficult to control all as a group. When all are related as threads spawned from a parent it would be easier.
It would be nice is launch files had a similar functionality, but that would complicate it too much......

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-05**:
Imo if all the processes were related debugging would be harder because one process failing would kill all the other ones (if you've ever used nodelets you'll get it). Moreover, that is the very essence of launch files to launch separate processes to let you add/remove whatever package you want.

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-10-05**:
You're absolutely right, especially in an experimental environment. But in a production/industrial environment you probably want something more convenient.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-05**:
You could do as you said directly from your nodes that would create the other threads (example in [#q217960](https://answers.ros.org/question/217960/how-to-write-a-thread-in-ros/) if you want). But the code would be really messy/disorganized.